# Mathematica Order of an Equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation

Is there a way to obtain the order of an ODE in mathematica.

For example, if i have `y''+5y` i want mathematica return `2` (beacuse it's a 2nd order equation). So, is it possible what i'm asking?

Comment: If you inspect the `FullForm` of your expression you'll probably get a clue.

Comment: Thanks, it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way to extract the value automatically:

```
 ode =  y'' + y' + y == 0 ;
 Max[Cases[ ode  , Derivative[n_][y] :> n , Infinity]]
```

> 2

note this just finds the largest derivative in the expression, it doesn't verify if the expression is actually an ode..

Comment: Awesome, that's all i need